# AWS CLI SNS Subscribe with multiple email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sns

How to subscribe to an SNS topic with multiple email addresses via CLI ?

Single subscription is going well as given below

```
aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:nnnnnn:abcd --protocol email --notification-endpoint  email1@gmail.com
```

when I try to submit to multiple emails with (, or a space), it doesn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you do this in AWS console? No. You have to run this multiple times with different email address.

Comment: able  to do this in console with a comma(,) separated email IDs.. but not in CLI

Answer (score 1):

The same you, I resolved with two lines Cli with two email
example:

- `aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:nnnnnn:abcd --protocol email --notification-endpoint  email1@gmail.com`
- `aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:nnnnnn:abcd --protocol email --notification-endpoint  email2@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. See these two articles:

1. Amazon takes multiple subscription endpoints [as a feature request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=206391). One person notes that Google GCM API does already have this functionality.
2. [Amazon documentation notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-topic.html) that the current way to subscribe multiple phone numbers or emails is to create multiple subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

There was an AWS Doc regarding providing a custom resource for this but I found their custom resource to not work... I was able to circumvent the issue by using a python script akin to the following:

```
import sys
import subprocess

f = open("MyEmails.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')

    result = subprocess.run(["aws sns subscribe --topic-arn MY_TOPIC_ARN --protocol email --notification-endpoint " + line], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    print(result.stdout)
```

Worked perfectly for me (MyEmails.txt just had an address on each line). Pretty sure default behavior of python subprocesses is to wait until process is finished so I wouldn't worry about overloading aws. Figured I'd post in case any script kiddies were struggling to help themselves and were lamenting the prospect of manually subscribing each address one at a time.